# How do I reference a cell for the sheet name in IMPORTRANGE function in Google Sheets when the sheet is in another workbook?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have two workbooks with several sheets in each. I have a dropdown to select the sheet name that I'm using for reference for URLs and to reference other sheets in the main book.

I successfully used `IMPORTRANGE` to get data from the other workbook when I put the sheet name in it.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Up9RK9bveEPN35iXq3V1QouJMgXELgzzoOdLnID5lU/edit?usp=sharing", "AMT!B2:M8")
```

AMT needs to be replaced with the value from another cell.

I've referenced cells in other sheets using `INDIRECT`

, but not sure how to do it in this case in this particular string.

I've tried doing it a number of different ways, and this is my most recent attempt

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Up9RK9bveEPN35iXq3V1QouJMgXELgzzoOdLnID5lU/edit?usp=sharing", "INDIRECT("'"&D4&"'!B2:M8")")
```

Comment: Welcome. 
Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: @marikamitsos you might consider upvoting the question since it's apparently clear enough to answer :) The author can't upvote your answer unless they have 15 reputation.

Comment: @Glorfindel The *"upvote"* encouragement actually goes to every one who can. As you know upvoted answers attract more attention. On the other hand, you are right. The OP's question is well formed and does worth the upvote. Especially for a new comer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the `INDIRECT` function in your formula.

All you need to do is use

```
=IMPORTRANGE("JUST_THE_ID_HERE", ""&D4&"!B2:M8")
```

*(where `D4` holds `AMT` or is a cell using a `Data Validation` dropdown list)*